# CDI Weld and AspectJ - org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException

Tags: java-ee-6, aspectj, cdi, jboss-weld

I get this error when using AspectJ and CDI.

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException:
>   WELD-001437 Normal scoped bean class
>   myPackageName.myClassName is not
>   proxyable because the type is final or
>   it contains a final method static
>   final java.lang.String
>   myPackageName.myClassName.myMethodName_aroundBody0(myPackageName.myClassName.,org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint).

If I remove AspectJ it works, but I don't want that. Please Help.

Comment: I can tell you the reason why this is happening, but I can't give you a solution.  There is some around advice being applied to myClassName.  Around advice will place the static final method in the byte code.  This method makes your class not proxy-able.  Best suggestion is to send a message to AspectJ users mailing list.

Comment: Link to mailing list: http://eclipse.org/aspectj/userlists.php

Comment: I figured out that too. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from AspectJ's mailing list, they proposed adding a compile time flag if the method should be final or not, as a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any flag that helped?